# How to make python use double quotes while writing a string to a file

Tags: python, string, file-io

I have a list in python

```
L = [[u'2014-12-02', 727.75], [u'2014-12-01', 733.65]]
```

to be written to a text file.

I want the file to contain

```
[["2014-12-02", 727.75], ["2014-12-01", 733.65]]
```

if I write `file.write(str(L))`

[['2014-12-02', 727.75], ['2014-12-01', 733.65]]

will be written to the file.

Comment: Why do you want it to look like that?  If you want JSON, use `json.dump` to write the file.

Comment: anyways give it a try - `file.write(str(L)).replace("'", '"')`

Comment: @NedBatchelder You are right, I want to write to a json file.

Comment: hey my comment is misleading (just useful in your particular example), correct approach is posted by @Pierre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the expected output is valid JSON, you can try:

```
import json

L = [[u'2014-12-02', 727.75], [u'2014-12-01', 733.65]]
with open("outfile", "w") as fdesc:
    json.dump(L, fdesc)
```

You might want to add `fdesc.write('\n')` after the `json.dump()` call.